# If you choose an answer to this question at random, what is the probability that you will be correct?

Tags: statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does this question even have an answer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76491/does-this-question-even-have-an-answer)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgxlS.jpg
Question: If you choose an answer to this question at random, what is the probability that you will be correct?

What is correct answer for:
A) 20%
B) 40%
C) 80%
D) 100%
E) 40%

Comment: I asked the mods to re-open this question. We will have to wait and see what happens, but I think this question is different to the one it's a "duplicate" of in an interesting way.

Comment: There's a meta thread about that, Qed