# Is this probability question wrong to begin with?

Tags: probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple-choice question about the probability of a random answer to itself being correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76491/multiple-choice-question-about-the-probability-of-a-random-answer-to-itself-bein)
>   [If you choose an answer to this question at random, what is the probability that you will be correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84237/if-you-choose-an-answer-to-this-question-at-random-what-is-the-probability-that)

[This question](https://plus.google.com/+RaymondJohnson/posts/CSXeyftovTJ)
appeared on my G+ feed:

> If you choose an answer to this question at random, what is the chance you will be correct?
>
> A) 25%
>   B) 50%
>   C) 60%
>   D) 25%

My friend and I have differing views on how to answer it. While both of us agree that 0% is the correct answer if one was to connect the answer chosen with the actual question, he argues that 50% is still a correct answer if we understand the question in a broader sense: If a question is asked and four answers are given, while two of them are correct, what is the chance that the correct answer would be chosen at random? Could 50% ever be considered correct?

Here's how my friend thinks: 
 There's a 1/4 chance that you've chosen the 'correct' answer. 
 Out of given options, two of them are 'correct'. 
 So, the chance that you're correct is 2/4.

Comment: I put in the question text into the post and replaced the link with the source of the problem.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks, and sorry for my laziness.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: suppose any of the answers is correct (literally: try them all), and derive a contradiction for each of them.

Comment: My reasoning would be along the lines that the answers given do not pertain to the question, and any mulitple choice question with 4 answers gives you a $25$% chance. So both A and D would be acceptable answers. Good question in general, though! (+1)

Comment: @EnviousPage That is my friend's reasoning too

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76491/multiple-choice-question-about-the-probability-of-a-random-answer-to-itself-bein/76494#76494) may be useful.