# Is this a question on probability? Or not a question at all?

Tags: probability, logic

If you choose an answer to this question at random, what is the chance you will be correct?

**A)** $25\%$

**B)** $50\%$

**C)** $60\%$

**D)** $25\%$

https://plus.google.com/+RaymondJohnson/posts/CSXeyftovTJ

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76491/multiple-choice-question-about-the-probability-of-a-random-answer-to-itself-bein?rq=1, the accepted answer.

Comment: The canonical question has "C) 0%", but earlier askings with "C) 60%" have been closed as duplicates too ([here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218256/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338116/), as well as several now deleted ones), after a chat discussion concluded that 76491 should be extended to cover that too.

Answer (score 2):

[Rob Elliot](https://plus.google.com/+RobElliottca/posts) answered this succintly:

> There is no ball in this option. The questions asks. If you choose an
> answer to this question at random, what is the chance you will be
> correct.
>
> It's not asking. If you choose an answer to this question at random,
> which of the answers represents the chance in percent you will be
> correct.
>
> Lets rephrase the question.
>
> If you choose an answer to this question at random, what is the chance
> you will select a fruit?
>
> - A) Mushroom
> - B) Potato
> - C) Carrot
> - D) Mushroom
>
> The question isn't tied to the answer being the only option. the
> wording of it is asking to calculate the chance of the out come
> independently of the provided answers.
>
> Thus
>
> - A) 25%
> - B) 50%
> - C) 60%
> - D) 25%
>
> If the Answer is 25%. There would have to be a 25% chance that you
> will select an answer of 25%. Because there are two options of 25% A
> and D there is a great statistical chance you will select an answer of
> 25%, thus neither is the correct answer.
>
> If the Answer is 50%. There would have to be a 50% chance you would
> select an answer equal to 50%. There is only one option of 50% and
> thus a lower Statistical chance you will select it and thus it is also
> incorrect.
>
> if the Answer is 60% you would have to have more then 4 options thus
> the answer is in correct.
>
> There for A, B, C, and D are all incorrect to the chance, and there
> for the chance of you selecting the correct answer from one of those 4
> options is 0%

Comment: This is of course assuming that a) b) c) & d) all have an equal probability of being chosen. There are many different ways to randomly choose something.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the answer you choose affects the question. Here is my two cents:

There is no correct answer, so the question is invalid.

If the answer is A or D, then the answer is 25% percent. However the chance of guessing right is then 50%, so the answer is B, a contradiction.

If the answer is B, then the answer is 50%, but the chance of guessing B is 25%, so the answer is A or D, a contradiction.

If the answer is C, then the answer is 60%, but again the chance of guessing right is 25%, so the answer is A or D.

Every choice leads to a contradiction. I believe this makes the question a paradox.