# On a scale of 1 to 10, how likely is it that this question is using binary?

Tags: probability, number-systems, binary, paradoxes

I just read this interesting [xkcd](http://xkcd.com) strip:

[image: On a scale of 1 to 10, how likely is it that this question is using binary?]

At first I thought it was funny, but as I got to ruminate a little over it, I was surprised to be unable to find an answer. As Karolis Juodelė pointed out, the probability is ε, as there is an infinite number of bases containing 1 and 10.

However, to get a finite answer, we can modify the puzzle like this:

> On a scale of 1 to 10, how likely is it that this question is using
>   binary vs. decimal?

So my question is: How should I solve this puzzle? Is there a correct answer at all? Is this what we call a *self-reference paradox*, like [Multiple-choice question about the probability of a random answer to itself being correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76491/120574)?

Comment: This is not a puzzle. There is no method of evaluating the likelihood of things happening in other peoples heads. If you just want to get the right base, say $1$.

Comment: Actually, if you assume that all possible interpretations of $1$ and $10$ are equally likely, the probability is $0$, because all bases have $1$ and $10$. This could be base $2$, base $10$ or base $123456$.

Comment: Base $10$, definitely base $10$, [all number bases are base $10$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166869/is-10-a-magical-number-or-i-am-missing-something)

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė, I meant the probability of binary vs. decimal. I edited my question for clarity now.

Comment: She doesn't know what a 4 is, so it is either binary, ternary or base-4.  (It can't be unary because 10 is a number).

Comment: @anustart in your modified version, if your question is in binary (the word in common sense), then I don't understand your "2" there, but still your question is in base 10. Alternatively, if your question is in, say, tridecimal (the word in common sense), then your question is not in base 2 but in base 10. So I will definitely vote for base 10, like I said above.

Comment: @peterwhy Oh, I see your point now, that base-10 is not the same as decimal if the question is base-2.

Comment: AFAIS if the question is decimal, the answer is `1+(10-1)\2 = 5.5`, but if it's binary, the answer is `1_2+(10_2-1_2)\10_2 = 1+(2-1)\2 = 1.5`.

Comment: This type of question is not to be taken seriously. But if I read the strip correctly, there is the indication that $4$ is not a known digit, so it is definitely not in decimal. Taking as (completely unreasonable) axiom that digits must be taken from the list $0,1,2,3,\ldots,9,A,B,\ldots$ in that order, the base can only be two, three, or four.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It is not a puzzle, I am asking whether there is a single correct answer that does not depend on itself. If there is an answer that will be the same no matter whether the question is binary or decimal. I didn't ask this question to "riddle" others.

Comment: @anustart: My point is that one should take into account the fact that the strip mentions the digit $4$ (twice), and something should be done with that information, which none of the comments/answer so far do (except one). Since the digit appears to cause puzzlement (my interpretation of the drawing), I conclude that it is **definitely not decimal**. And asking about (only) binary vs. decimal is certainly not implied by the strip, other bases must be considered too.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I'm looking for a generic answer, an answer that is correct no matter what happens in the asker's head.

Comment: @anustart: MU..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If I understand correctly, $10$ means certainly in binary and $1$ means certainly in decimal)

To answer your modified question, if I were to think like in your last comment (2014-01-11 20:48:42Z), then I would answer:

> As likely as $1+\dfrac{10-1}{1+1} = \dfrac{11}{1+1}$

But for me, I choose to answer

> As likely as $1+1+\dfrac{1+1-10}{(1+1)^{1+1+1}}$

Comment: If the question is decimal, the scale is 1 to 10, which means 1 = never binary and 10 = always binary, and also 5.5 will be a 50/50 chance. If the question is binary, the scale is 1 to 2, which means 2 = always binary and 1.5 (or 1.1 as binary) will be a 50/50 chance. Therefore I'd choose to answer "If decimal 5.5, if binary 1.1". Is there a single answer that will be correct independent on its base?

Comment: How about `(b+1)/2` where `b` is the base?

Comment: That is equivalent to the first answer I gave above: $\frac{11}{1+1}$.

Comment: Ok, then I just realized the if the question is binary, the answer is binary as well. +1!

Comment: But then, why assign 50:50 chance to 1 and 10? If the question is in decimal, then 1, if binary then 10.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. You're absolutely right. Thanks!