# Mathematical notation for a self reference (in a rebus)

Tags: notation, recursion

I am a layperson and I am trying to wrap my head around how to formally write down this rebus:

[image]

How do I define the self reference?

Comment: What "self-reference" ?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76491/multiple-choice-question-about-the-probability-of-a-random-answer-to-itself-bein

Comment: - What "self-reference" ?
- "this question"