# Self-referential multiple-choice question

Tags: logic, paradoxes

I came across this question, which I believe cannot be satisfactorily answered, but I'm not completely sure. Can you tell me if it has a answer?

```
If you choose the answer to this question at random,
what is the chance that you will be correct?
a) 25%
b) 50%
c) 60%
d) 25%
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple-choice question about the probability of a random answer to itself being correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76491/multiple-choice-question-about-the-probability-of-a-random-answer-to-itself-bein) (for reviewers: only option (c) is different from the duplicating target, but 60% clearly doesn't make more sense than 0%)

Answer (score 3):

Correct (on the typical assumptions we can only pick one answer, that the selection is uniformly random, etc.). The question is actually a fairly common paradox. The cause is the sort of self-referential nature of the question.

- Typically for multiple-choice questions with four answers, at random there is a $25\%$ chance to get it right. But two answers have that choice.
- So logically it would be $50\%$, but only one choice corresponds to that. So you're damned if you pick either one: if $50\%$ is correct, the odds are $25\%$ and if $25\%$ is correct the odds are $50\%$.
- $60\%$ simply makes no sense, being not a multiple of $25\%$, and can be ruled out outright.

So as it is posed, there is no correct answer.