# What is the probability of randomly select the option $25\%$ from the picture below?

Tags: probability

The image shows a contestant being asked what the probability is of randomly selecting the right answer. $4$ options are given: $2$ being $25\%$ and the other two being $50\%$ and $0\%$.

[image]

Basically I’m in disagreement with someone over this question. The question in the picture is a paradox but I think the probability of randomly choosing the option $25\%$ is $2/4$ or $1/2$ since it is repeated, while my friend believes it is $1/3$ since there are technically three options. Anyone able to give a conclusive answer?

Comment: [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76491/multiple-choice-question-about-the-probability-of-a-random-answer-to-itself-bein)